# Extract watermark from image

Tags: image-processing, watermark

I've got 2 versions of 1 image

[image: 1 image without watermark]
[image: the same image, with a alpha-blended watermark]

Is it possible to get a transparent png file representing this watermark? Can ImageMagick do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SilverMonkey has the basic solution using Imagemagick. But the request was for a transparent PNG. So I will add a little bit more to his code to make it transparent by adding -alpha copy.

```
convert kitty2.jpg kitty1.jpg -compose minus -composite -auto-level -alpha copy watermark1.png
```

[image]

Here is another approach that makes a binary mask for the watermark by thresholding. But it leaves a lot of noise. So I use some morphology open to remove the noise and then some morpholgy close to try to fill in where the text is broken up. Then I add -alpha copy to make the image transparent. But the text is white and the original watermark was light gray. So I turn alpha off, multiply by 0.75 to reduce the brightness of the white letters to gray without affecting the alpha channel. Then turn the alpha channel back on.

```
convert kitty2.jpg kitty1.jpg -compose minus -composite -threshold 0.6% -morphology open diamond:1 -morphology close octagon:1 -alpha copy -alpha off -evaluate multiply 0.75 -alpha on watermark2.png
```

[image]

For more on morphology, see https://imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/

Comment: Seems to be a more sophisticated approach then mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal by calculating the difference between both images (subtract the pixels of both images and calculate the absolute value). This will result in:
[image: Subtracted image]
ImageMagick seems to be capable of image subtraction, [look here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=29191):
The code:

```
convert image2 image1 -compose minus -composite result
```